# How can i hardcode picture size and ratio

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I start creating my first Prestashop. All pictures have 800x800px, but when i add new product i have sth like here [1st pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL1fu.png)

In the inspector i found size of this box:

Rendered size:  255 × 302 px
Rendered aspect ratio:  255∶302
Intrinsic size: 350 × 415 px
Intrinsic aspect ratio: 70∶83

also padding is 255x302.359
[padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfWlP.png)

when i change padding to 255x255 i see square, but pic is destroyed by ratio. Can someone explain me in which file i can hardcode padding and intrinsic size? Because I don't see that in theme css. (the same problem is on different themes)

Comment: Try using the CSS property `object-fit: cover;` on the images. Be careful, as there is a difference between setting the width of the image being loaded and fitting the image inside of its respective element. Also, the numbers that you see are the dimensions of the element itself, not the padding. The padding would be in green, not blue. You may also have to explicitly set the dimensions of the image element itself. Another "hack" to get a square is to use `padding-bottom: 100%`, since padding  (as a percentage) is derived from the parent element.

Comment: nothing happen when i added object-fit

Comment: Why, inside of the file that the images are contained. Likely under `/views/templates`. https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-file-structure/

Comment: when i add padding-bottom i have bigger space between rows

Comment: Here is the Mozilla documentation for the CSS `object-fit` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit See the example that uses `cover`.

Comment: Try this article for the `padding-bottom: 100%`trick https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: ok, i found correct place for object-fit, i added also height and width in px and now it works. thank you sooo much for help!

Comment: yw  glad i could help!

Comment: object-fit cover will crop your images if it has to - depending on aspect ratios. object-fit contain will ensure the whole photo is always shown.